# How to properly use the the MegaCli command for a LSI Megaraid Secure erase for an SSD?

Tags: ssd, megaraid, megacli

I tried the following commands but I keep getting a invalid command error. It seems to properly pick up the correct controller, drive slot, and adapter though. I currently don't have a screenshot of the exact error but it says it can not start the secure erase.

```
MegaCli -SecureErase Start[Simple[-PhysDrv[252:0,252:1]] -a0
MegaCli -SecureErase Start[Simple] [-PhysDrv[252:0,252:1]] -a0
MegaCli -SecureErase Start[Simple] -PhysDrv[252:0,252:1] -a0
```

Also tried all the examples above using just one drive slot like below.

```
MegaCli -SecureErase Start[Simple[-PhysDrv[252:0]] -a0
```

Spent over an hour trying to figure out the correct syntax from the manual. I am trying to do a secure erase on the SSD since they were heavily used prior so I want to refresh the performance.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are just reading the manual too literally.

With the exception of the list of devices I don't believe any of the brackets go in the actual command.

Your command should be something like this

```
MegaCli -SecureErase Start Simple -PhysDrv [252:0,252:1] -a0
```

(You may need to escape the remaining brackets depending on your shell.)

Comment: +1. The MegaCLI help is pretty awful.  As an alternative, LSI now publish a tool called StorCli, which replaces MegaCLI.  Might be worth looking at.

Comment: Awesome, going to try this tonight or tomorrow night. Is the Simple secure erase good to use for refreshing SSD's to improve their performance again?